# How can I change datasource for different datasource in XtraReport( Devexpress )?

Tags: devexpress, xtrareport

in XtraReport, I have a project. I send this project to many people. But the data of this people is different.(Not column and table, just the records are different.). How can I change datasource of this project easily?

Comment: What type of `DataSource` are you using?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254494%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I use this way to change my datasource:

In the code behind of your report, in the beginning I add this line  **sqlDataSource1.Connection.ConnectionString = "yourconectiondatasource"**:

Example:

```
   Public Sub New()
    MyBase.New()

    'This call is required by the Designer.
    InitializeComponent()

    'Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call

    ' GET THE DINAMIC DATASOURCE
    sqlDataSource1.Connection.ConnectionString = "yourconectiondatasource"

End Sub
```

Note: You should put in the designer the sqlDatasource1 in public mode because in default is in private mode.